# GeoDjango and Mixer. 'PointField' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, geodjango, faker

I have a `Location` model that defined (roughly) like this:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gis = models.PointField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Whenever I try to `mixer.blend('app.Location')` I get:

```
AttributeError: Mixer (app.Location): type object 'PointField' has no attribute '_meta'
```

It works when I blend it with the field set to None or Point, but I wonder if there is a way to set it up so it can do it on its own, especially since faker can generate this data.

Comment: Can you please provide full code sample on how you are calling `mixer.blend`?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis the usual: `from mixer.backend.django import mixer; mixer.blend('some.Model')`. Anyway. I've just found out about `mixer.register` - it's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: this issue seems to be about the same problem: https://github.com/klen/mixer/issues/142

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mixer.register`](http://mixer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#mixer.main.Mixer.register) allows you to customize the way you want your data generated. In this case

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point


mixer.register(
    'app.Location',
    gis=lambda: Point(
        float(mixer.faker.latitude()),
        float(mixer.faker.longitude()),
    ),
)
```

does the job.